# Waiting For child to finish

Tags: c, fork, infinite-loop

I want my parent process to wait till all child processes and children of child processes are finished. I have used `while(waitpid(-1,NULL,0))` but it just created an infinite loop. I have also used `waitpid(pid_child,&status,WNOHANG)` but it just ends when the child process ends not children of child processes.

NOTE: `pid_child` is PID that I got from `fork()` in parent process.

Comment: Post your code instead of explaining it.

Comment: @LPs. I think the question is pretty good n clear. I wouldn't count the missing semicolons against OP.

Answer (score 4):

A process may only wait on its immediate children.  It cannot wait on children-of-children.

The best you can do is have the children wait on the children-of-children and have the parent wait on the children.

Comment: agreed about "the best you can do...". But if a child terminates wtih a '
'grand child' still running I would expect the parent to become the new parent process of the 'grand child': Now `waitpid()` should be possible.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt When a process's parent terminates, the `init` process becomes the parent.  It doesn't matter if the grandparent is still running or not.

Comment: You're right, by default, `init` becomes the parent, I was wrong. But on Linux since 3.4 that behaviour can be changed by calling `prctl( PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER, 1, 0, 0, 0 );` in the parent